# Block TCP connection to certain domain

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, tcp, procmon

Using ProcMon.exe, I see that I got an outgoing TCP request to

```
MyUser-PC.home:54988 -> ec1-51-49-47-232.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:https
```

And then an incoming TCP request:

```
MyUser-PC.home:54988 -> ec1-51-49-47-232.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:https
```

I have no idea what this is / which software initiates it.

How would I find out which program does this?

And how would I configure my Windows Firewall with a custom rule to block anything incoming / outgoing containing "amazonaws"?

Comment: Use [tcpview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) tool to view which program connects to it.

Comment: Many companies, including Netflix, use AmazonAWS to host their content. I highly recommend you not block access to anything containing that string in their DNS name.